# How can I create a custom NHibernate configuration property?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, configuration, xsd

I'm currently working on creating a custom connection provider for HNibernate very similar to the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416813/nhibernate-and-database-connection-failover).  In it, they specify a separate connection string within the hibernate.cfg.xml parameters.  However, when I go to add this new parameter, like so...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.provider">MyNameSpace.FailoverConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect,NHibernate</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.connection_string">[primary connection string]</property>
        <property name="connection.failover_connection_string">[failover connection string]</property>
        <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
        ...
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

... I am treated to this exception message:

```
InnerException  {"The 'name' attribute is invalid - The value 'connection.failover_connection_string' is invalid according to its datatype 'String' - The Enumeration constraint failed."}  System.Exception {System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException}
```

My question is: is it even possible to add custom properties to the NHibernate configuration file?  If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to add properties to the NHibernate configuration file because it's schema-validated (and you can't change the schema).

Anyway, that's **not** the place to put anything other than the NHibernate core configuration itself.

Everything else should be in its own location, be it a custom section in the `app.config` file, a key in the `appSettings` section, etc.