# How to use database as backup/failover in hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

My application is based on the hibernate to fetched data from a mysql server. This mysql server is replicated to another mysql server instance. Today, I got a downtime as the primary database server was gone down without any notice. To avoid any future accidental problem, I am planing to add a functionality that will enable system to connect to secondary database if it finds the primary down.

Is there exists a way by which, I can leverage hibernate library to enable this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created following class after getting an idea form [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416813/nhibernate-and-database-connection-failover.)
It seems to be working well. I don't know if this is a good approach at all.

```
package com.vsd.server.hibernate;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider;

public class FailoverConnectionProvider extends C3P0ConnectionProvider {

    String password;
    String username;
    String connectionString;
    String failover_connstring;

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {

        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, username, password);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(failover_connstring, username, password);
        }

        if(conn == null){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Database connection was not initialized");
        }

        return conn;

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Properties properties) throws HibernateException {
        failover_connstring = properties.getProperty("hibernate.connection.failover.url");

        if (StringUtils.isBlank(connectionString)
                && StringUtils.isBlank(failover_connstring)
                && StringUtils.isBlank(username)
                && StringUtils.isBlank(password)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize connection provider for hibernate");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This could be another way. But your current implementation is very basic (no connection pooling) and is IMO not suitable for production use.

Answer (score 8):

> Today, I got a downtime as the primary database server was gone down without any notice.

Well, that's the first thing you should fix (with proper monitoring).

> (...) Is there exists a way by which, I can leverage hibernate library to enable this functionality?

To my knowledge, Hibernate doesn't really provide any facility for this. Personally, I would investigate the fail-over support of MySQL and its JDBC driver. I can't provide a very concrete answer because I haven't implemented this with MySQL but here are some pointers:

- [MySQL Failover Strategy using State Management, introducing MPP - Part 1](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/failover-strategy-part1.html)
- [21.3.4.1. Driver/Datasource Class Names, URL Syntax and Configuration Properties for Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)
- [21.3.4.6. Using Master/Slave Replication with ReplicationConnection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-replication-connection.html)

And, as mentioned at the bottom of the latest link above (and also in [this comment](http://blogs.oracle.com/carriergrademysql/entry/how_to_use_jdbc_connector#comment-1227938166000)):

> You may also want to investigate the Load Balancing JDBC Pool (lbpol) tool, which provides a wrapper around the standard JDBC driver and enables you to use DB connection pools that includes checks for system failures and uneven load distribution. For more information, see [Load Balancing JDBC Pool (lbpool)](http://code.tailrank.com/lbpool).

Comment: What do you think of the program I have added to the application?

Comment: Can you suggest some monitoring process, for proper monitoring

Comment: @Vijay Here are some: [Zenoss](http://community.zenoss.org/index.jspa), [Centreon](http://www.centreon.com/), [Opsview](http://www.opsview.com/downloads/download-opsview-community)

Comment: Are you kidding? If it weren't open source i'd be already asking for my money back. I know databases and network links are supposed not to fail, but by supposed I mean they do eventually fail. We have 3rd party providers, public networks, accounting failures... lots of things happen...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add failover feature a dataSource level (any type of database). There are few libraries for that. For example:

1. "Sequoia"
2. "FODS – Fail-over data-source"

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way check the link below
http://cmanolescu.wordpress.com/2010/05/15/backup-and-restore-database-using-hibernate/

Comment: Please add the details here as well. Just providing links as answers is frowned upon.