# NHibernate w/ database mirroring via Failover Partner in connection string

Tags: c#, .net, database, hibernate, nhibernate

I'll preface this question by saying I am using `NHibernate v3.2`.
Let's say I have a connection string like the following (the key here is the `Failover Partner`):

```
Data Source=Server1\Instance;Failover Partner=Server2\Instance;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Integrated Security=True;
```

I found the following article related to this topic in a `hibernate` forum:
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=979764

One user mentions the following:
`We had a slight hiccup with the way we were caching our NHibernate session and had to add a method that verifies the session's connection is still open when we pull it out of the call context.`

**Does NHibernate support this database mirroring option out of the box because it uses ADO.net?**
**Is there any special cases that I need to watch out for when using a connection string like this?**

Answer (score 2):

It supports this and have proven this to myself in both test and production systems using 3.2.  It also works fine with 3.3.

The only thing I had to watch was that I display the database server in the footer by reading configuration settings.  This will still display data source and have not found an easy way to display if Failover partner is in use.